# Time since epoch in c++ library used by esp32

Tags: c++, time, c++-chrono, esp32

I'm trying to create a library in `c++` to be used by an esp32 and possibly to be used in linux or windows.

Right now, I have a piece of code that gets the time since epoch in millisecounds, this is 1 january 1970. This works perfectly in linux. Although, when the esp32 runs this code it returns the time since the program started. Probabily the source of my problem is that the library I'm using, `chrono`, uses the method `millis()`, which in case of the arduino returns the time since the program started.

```c
milliseconds ms = duration_cast< milliseconds >(
    system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()
);
```

My question is, is there any way of getting the correct time since epoch in `c++` code that works in all the platforms ?

Comment: isn't epoch seconds since 1970? you get the time by configuring SNTP https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/ESP32/examples/Time/SimpleTime/SimpleTime.ino

Comment: I did not understand your question. Thank you, I looked into it and managed to get the time format of my zone, but really what I want is the milliseconds since 1 january 1970 at midnight which is the unix epoch time :)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Comment: Never mind Juraj. I fixed it by using the macro:
```#if defined(ESP32)
const char* ntpServer = "pool.ntp.org";
const long  gmtOffset_sec = 0;
const int   daylightOffset_sec = 3600;
configTime(gmtOffset_sec, daylightOffset_sec, ntpServer);
#endif```

Comment: @FilipeAmador, please add your answer not as a comment but as an answer to your question so you can close it. This will also allow people to vote on your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fixed it by using the macro:

```
#if defined(ESP32) 
const char* ntpServer = "pool.ntp.org"; 
const long gmtOffset_sec = 0; 
const int daylightOffset_sec = 3600; 
configTime(gmtOffset_sec, daylightOffset_sec, ntpServer); 
#endif
```

This way the esp32 can get the time from the ntpServer instead of getting the time since the program started.